# How can you get the page count of the selected documents in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

My Google Drive has a large number of documents at this. Occasionally, I'll want to look at various statistics about the documents I've created (e.g. total number of pages I've written, total number of pages in certain selected documents, etc.) How do you do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can check multiple documents at once, but to find statistics for a single Google Doc try `Tools -> Word count` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

[image: Menubar option for word count]

[image: Word count window]

[Via Google Support: "Count the words in a document"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/39003)

Answer (score -1):

You can see the page count on the scroll bar as you scroll or pull it.