# How to word count multiple documents?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have a Google Drive folder containing dozens of Google Docs.

Is there a way to run a word count on a selection of files (or all of the folder contents), and read either a sum of the counted words across all files, or a list of the word counts per file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view the number of files in a folder from Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112435/how-can-i-view-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-from-google-drive)

Comment: @pjmg: I don't see how this is a duplicate. Your suggestion talks about counting the number of _files_, not words.

Comment: with this code https://stackoverflow.com/q/38821920 to read a google doc, then you just have to count what you need.

Comment: The question doesn't look to be a good fit for this site. By one side it doesn't share search/research efforts, it might be assumed to be a recommendation request,  it might even be a duplicate of [How can you get the page count of the selected documents in Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105315/88163). There might be multiple ways to do this, all of them requiring other components. Google Docs Add-ons, Google Apps Script, Google Drive API / Google Docs API, third party tools.